# FilterOptions Errors with Riemann Sum Notebook on Math World

Tags: packages, code-review, inheritance

I am trying to run the notebook for a maximum (upper) integration calculation (hopefully, symbolically).

I am using the [*notebook*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html) available at *Wolfram Math World* (upper left of web page).

When I trying running the code and single example, I am getting all sorts of errors (too many to list). However, the first two errors are the likely culprits and are:

> ```
>  Get::noopen: Cannot open Utilities`FilterOptions`. >>
>
>  Needs::nocont: Context Utilities`FilterOptions` was not created when Needs was evaluated. >>
> ```

How can the

```
BeginPackage["RiemannSum`", {"Utilities`FilterOptions`"}]
```

`FilterOptions` issue be resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `Compatibility/tutorial/Utilities/FilterOptions` says:

> The functionality of `FilterOptions` is provided by the kernel function `FilterRules`.

Although the syntax is not identical. You have to change two things in the code:

> ```
> BeginPackage["RiemannSum`", {"Utilities`FilterOptions`"}]
> ```

to

```
BeginPackage["RiemannSum`"]
```

And

```
Begin["Private`"]
```

to

```
Begin["`Private`"];
FilterOptions[s_, r___] := Sequence @@ FilterRules[Flatten[{r}], Options[s]];
```

And it seems to work:

```
RiemannSumPlot[x^4 - 3 x^2 + 1, {x, -1, 1.9, 29},  ShowEstimate -> False, AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}]
```

[image]